# Reinserting live USB after pulling out does not re-enable reading

Tags: usb, dvd, live-cd, peripherals

If I run Linux live from USB stick or external DVD drive or external SD card reader, I can pull the card or take the disc out of the drive, re-insert it and it works normally.

But If I **disconnect the external DVD drive, etc. from the port and re-connect it, it does not work again, until restart.**
 - Not reading files or stating applications from boot DVD.
 - Masses of SquashFS errors.

What is the reason? 
How do I solve that problem without violating a Linux/Unix/BSD philosophy? (*ability to solve problems without needing a solution that involves a reboot)*

The same effect happens to Mint, but other distributions are not tested yet. (CentOS, Gentoo; Arch, FreeBSD(!=Linux, I know.),SuSE,etc.)

---

Problem:
The DVD drive was re-allocated to sr2 instead of sr0.
But I can not access mount/umount.

Comment: Can you please explain "It does not work again"? How do you know it is not working?

Comment: @Stumblebee It does not start programs off the disc anymore and gives SquashFS errors.